# Having 2 textField.delagate = self cancels one of them out

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am trying to make it so when I click the reutrn/done key on the keyboard the keyboard will hide, but for some reason when I try to delegate both the textfields, whenever i click on the nameTextField it will think im pressing the jobTextField and display that pickerView. Does anyone understand this?

ViewController Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {`

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var jobPickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBAction func setupDoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if (nameTextField.text?.isEmpty == false) {
            defaults.set(nameTextField.text, forKey: "name")
            defaults.set(jobTextField.text, forKey: "job")
        }
    }

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let jobs = ["Real Estate Agent","Retail","Teacher", "Student", "Other"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        jobPickerView.isHidden = true;
        jobPickerView.delegate = self
        jobPickerView.dataSource = self
        jobTextField.delegate = self

        nameTextField.delegate = self
        nameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "setupDoneButtonSegue") {
            let svc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            svc.firstDataPassed = nameTextField.text
            svc.secondDataPassed = jobTextField.text
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return jobs.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return jobs[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        jobTextField.isHidden = false;
        jobPickerView.isHidden = true;
        jobTextField.text = jobs[row];
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        jobTextField.isHidden = true
        jobPickerView.isHidden = false;
        return false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of you are setting `UITextFieldDelegate` for both fields, you need to add condition in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` so it will show `pickerView` only for `jobTextField`.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    jobTextField.isHidden = false
    jobPickerView.isHidden = true
    if jobTextField == textField {
        jobTextField.isHidden = true
        jobPickerView.isHidden = false
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @SkyEnterprises Welcome mate :)

Comment: @SkyEnterprises Rafaela is also right you need to hide the pickerview by default if its name field please check the edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify what textField are you using when enter in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

There's an example:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    // Using this is better to add more textFileds later..

    switch textField {
    case jobTextField:
        jobTextField.isHidden = true
        jobPickerView.isHidden = false
        return false
    case nameTextField:
        jobTextField.isHidden = false
        jobPickerView.isHidden = true
        return true
    default:
        // Do something
        return true
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer works too but since the comment above was first ill mark that one as the answer.

Comment: There's no problem :)